# Is it possible to hide environment variables from other people who access my code?

Tags: node.js, security, devops, web-development-server

Is this a concern that exists, and how do people handle it? What if someone inserts code like this to extract valuable info:

```
    router.get('/normal/route/:parameter', function(req, res){
        if (req.params.parameter === "secretHackerParemeter234") {
            return res.send(process.env.API_KEY);
        }
        // normal functionality here
    });
```

I've looked on google, and there are many articles explaining why env variables are helpful, for example to keep api keys off of Github. But I'm wondering what are measures to protect them from someone who works on your code.

Comment: If you don’t trust your teammates, let them work on the `staging` environment and keep your `production` env variables for yourself.